# Jquery bounce animate function to work on document load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have an image in a html document and when the webpage loads i want the image to bounce. I have a jquery function that does this only when the image is clicked on. I can't figure out how to make this work onLoad...

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
  div { margin-left: 500px; margin-top: 200px; width: 100px; height: 80px; position: relative; }
</style>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

$("#logo").click(function () {
      $(this).effect("bounce", { times:4, distance:200 }, 400);
});

  });
  </script>
</head>
<body> 
 <div id="logo"><img src="http://visionhelp.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/soccer-ball.jpg"/> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for checking this out. Much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#logo").effect("bounce", { times:4, distance:200 }, 400);
});
```

or, using a more modern style of document ready function:

```
$(function () {
    $("#logo").effect("bounce", { times:4, distance:200 }, 400);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This work for you:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#logo').effect("bounce", {
        times: 4,
        distance: 200
    }, 400).click(function() {
        $(this).effect("bounce", {
            times: 4,
            distance: 200
        }, 400);
    });
})
```

With a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whAZa/)** example

Comment: You can reduce your code by by keep the effect logic only foe click handler and executing the click handler on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger the `click` event on page load. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#logo").click(function () {
      $(this).effect("bounce", { times:4, distance:200 }, 400);
  })
  .click();//Will trigger the click event on page load
});
```

If you don't want this effect on logo click but just on page load then use this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).effect("bounce", { times:4, distance:200 }, 400);
});
```

Comment: In your second example I think you need to start with '#logo' rather than 'this', since this would apply to the whole document rather than limited to the object with an id=logo.